# Which is Better use or don't use string.xml?

Tags: android

Commonly android programmer use string.xml because it recommended by ADT android like android studio or eclipse (at least that what I thought) , but  lately I think using string.xml is waste of resources ... we can directly named the text on layout widget or app name directly instead of declare it on string.xml and call it on layout later ...

Can any one explain that my thought is right or wrong ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to directly name your text. But resources are really helpful when your text have to change depending of your users' configurations, such as language. That's why it is recommanded to do it this way.

It is also a way to avoid having too many informations to manage in one file for the developper so he can focus on the way he wants his layout to look like. Android IDEs make string resources easy to use for you. I would recommand you keep using them.

Answer (score 2):

There is a reason you use strings.xml and that is to support multiple locale just to provide one point. Also its easily extensible as compared to hardcoding your strings...

Comment: You can also add factorization. Imagine you want to change a title you have everywhere in your application.

Answer (score 1):

One of its use that You can use multiple languages for your app using string.xml

So in the folder values you would have strings.xml with this content:

```
<string name="hello">Hello</string>
```

In values-fr a strings.xml with this content:

```
<string name="hello">Bonjour</string>
```

It will automatically pick up your default language selected.

and other is, suppose you are using same string multiple places. so in XML, it would be easy to change by changing in only one place.

Answer (score 0):

If you `use string.xml` you will have a `global access` to the all string variables used in the application .

If you `hard-code` the string values in the xml resources , you will have `slight improvement in UI rendering`